# How to add a project in the build path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two project in Eclipse Indigo and I d like to add the first in the second one.

So what I do is right click on the second project: `Build Path -> Configure Build Path  -> Projects -> Add` , and I select the first project.

When I run my application I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when it tries to access a class from the first project.

Why do I get this exception? Is there anything else I need to I do other than just adding the project in the build path?

Comment: Thank you guys. It seems to be working with your suggestion.

However how do I propagate changes in the first project to the second one?

What I mean is, I am modifing the first project but the second one keeps an old version of the first one. I did everything related to refresh, update, remove and add again to the build path etc... but nothing seems to work. 

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right click the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> **Order and Export**

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export, and select the referenced project.

Answer (score 0):

you must check the project in "Order and Export" tab in your projects build path properties.